# Heapsort of a struct

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, queue, heapsort

I am trying to implement heapsort in C++ that would take a structure of two integers in it and sort them in a lexicographical order. However, Visual Studio throws at me a bunch of errors, like

```
Error   8   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from 'const lol'
```

I don't really knows what that means, but I think something wrong is in the very declaration. I did this:

```
struct lol {
    int num1;
    int num2;
};
```

And I declared the priority_queue like this:

```
priority_queue<lol> q;
```

Comment: Did you define a comparison operator for `lol`? Show the code for it.

Comment: Actually, I did not. Can you tell me more about what that is ? I've found some articles about those operators, but I do not understand how  they works.

Comment: By default in order to sort containers in the `std` library, they use the less than operator: `operator <` This is why it's complaining that it can't find them. It must exist in the class first.

Comment: Should I define it outside the struct ?

Comment: @CLU, doesn't matter. If the comparison need access to the private data of `lol` define it as a member function (`operator<(const lol&)`) otherwise go for a free function (`operator<(const lol&, const lol&)`).

Comment: Why is there the & sign after the type ? And how should the body of the function look like if I want to sort in lexicographical order ?

Comment: btw pair<int,int> already has a operator<, consider using it.

Comment: How would I change the < operator of a int pair, if I want to sort the pairs in reversed order according to their second value (when pair1.first==pair2.first)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type `lol` needs an `operator<` function so that the `priority_queue` knows how to sort them. The compiler doesn't provide one by default. There are a few options.

To get the code to compile without changing the declaration of `priority_queue<lol> q;` you will need to provide the operator. You can declare it as a free function. Here's an example; assuming you would sort a `lol` struct based on the `num1` field (not sure how you *actually* want to do it).

```
bool operator< (const lol &left, const lol &right) {
    return left.num1 < right.num1;
}
```

Note, if `num1` was private, you'd need to make the operator a friend of `lol`.